# Getting authentication token from one processor and body from second processor in an invoke http processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to Nifi & needed your help.
My Problem statement is : I need to get an access token by sending user-id, password & other details in the body of an authentication api. I am having some data of users in my database. I need to get these data and run a post API say API 2. This data needs to be then sent into the body of the API 2 body along with the access token in the header.

I have made the data flow, where I inserted the body using a Replace text processor. Also I have fetched the data from database and got into order. I am not able to send the access token and body data together. When sending both the flows seperately, the token is not taken in the requests that contain the body. I also tried to use merge content. But the merge content added the access token in the body that is to be sent in API 2 which creates a problem.
I need a way such that both the token and body are sent.
Please help!
And thanks in advance. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pazy.jpg)